# mysql lookup table schema

Tags: mysql, schema, storage-engines

What's a more detailed command for seeing table properties than `show tables`? In particular, I need to know what storage engines are being used in a database that I've inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could query the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) tables directly.

```
SELECT `table_name`, `engine`
FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
WHERE `table_schema` = 'your_db'
ORDER BY `table_name` ASC
```

Comment: Why all those obsolete backticks ` ? Has nothing to do with SQL and MySQL can also handle standard double quotes ", if you need them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Comment: @Frank Heikens: Old habits die hard. Is there an advantage to using double quotes to quote identifiers? If not, why bother with the additional config?

Comment: When working with other databases as well, backticks are a huge PITA :( And there is no need for it, MySQL can handle double quotes as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
show table status like '<tablename>'
show create table <tablename>
describe <tablename>
show indexes from <tablename>
```